# TextMesh pro Unity: instantiated text prefab wont change it's position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text, 2d, instantiation

I am working on a 2D game and the text prefab that I instatiate doesn't position itself over the gameObject clicked (which is the goal). I've set the Canvas as parent of the prefab via script after spawning it and it doesnt change position.

```
    // creating hit text
    GameObject canvas = GameObject.Find("Canvas");
    GameObject hit = (GameObject)Instantiate(hitText, transform.position,Quaternion.identity);
    hit.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);
    hit.transform.position = transform.position;
```

P.S: this sample code worked with a text made with the Unity Text Editor. Does that mean TexhMesh Pro won't support this function?

Comment: `transform.position` is referring to the position of the object this code is attached to, not the GameObject that was clicked.

Comment: the code is attached to the object that was clicked @Draco18s

Comment: Then more information is needed.

Comment: @Draco18s such as ? in case the note i left escaped your attention:
"This sample of code worked with a text made with the Unity Text Editor, does that mean TexhMesh Pro won't support this function ?"

Comment: That wouldn't make any sense and I can't see anything in the documentation to support that assertion.

Comment: @Draco18s totaly agree, which is why i hoped that posting a quesiton about it will help, it was my last hope to find out what's wrong.

Comment: Try using RectTransform instead of Transform. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.html

Comment: @Woltus yes i did already...rectTransform , TextMeshProGuiTransform...nothing works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might have this problem please understand that I made sure that the instantiated text is a child object of the canvas. The problem was that my text has been changed on start by an attached animation. The script above was working fine but the animation was changing it. 
You can easely fix this problem by setting the parent of the text to an empty GameObject, which then serves as a container for the text, allowing the text to change its position relatively to it's parent only.